# Connection to PC Dropping and Reconnecting

Tags: usb, nokia-lumia-730

When I connect my phone to my laptop via a USB cable, it is connecting and disconnecting about every other second. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried it with a different PC? (Preferably a desktop.)

Comment: Yes in other laptops its working.

Comment: If you have an externally-powered USB hub handy, try that. I have the same issue sometimes with my tablet, and it seems that it may not be giving steady enough power to the phone, therefore dropping and regaining the connection.